# Check if parent category hasn't been published when calling its related articles?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder, laravel-8

I use [laravel-nestedset](https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset) for creating the category of articles.

> Laravel: 8 / laravel-nestedset: 5.0.3

**Table categories**

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->increments('id');
      NestedSet::columns($table);
      $table->boolean('publish')->default(true);
      ...
```

**Table articles**

```
Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
        ...
```

I have created a branch and a sub-branch in the category table like this:

```
news > politics
```

I have also created two articles and insert them into the '**news**' branch and '**politics**' branch.

> **article1** in **news**
>
> **article2** in **politics**

Everything works!

---

Now I have a scenario. I want to get all the articles that are only in the published categories. (**publish = 1**).

I try this:

```
$query = \App\Article;

$query->where(function($query)
  {
      $query->whereHas('category' , function ($query) {$query->where('publish' , true ); });
  });
```

However, this code works only for the current article category (not for the parent of that category).

Let me explain more with an example.

> `pulish` in "**news**" is false. (`pulish = 0`)
>
> `pulish` in "**politics**" is true. (`pulish = 1`)

Now I want to get all articles with (`pulish=1`) in its category. The above query code returns me '**article2**.' I expect no article to be returned to me. Because even "**politics**" is `publish=1`, its parent (**news**) is `publish=0`, so related articles should not be published. How can change the query code to support the parent (or even more its top parents)?